# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. when resetting provider

Tags: flutter, provider, flutter-provider

This code is working fine and resetting provider element but why this error in console.
calling this function on init() in stateful class;

```
 Future getPlotsGraphDataAccordingToCategoryAndDate(context,CategoryId,CategoryName,date) async {
    var getRepresentationProvider =
    Provider.of<RepresentationProvider>(context, listen: false);

    getRepresentationProvider.resetPerticularCategoryDataAccordingDate();

    var response = await http.get(url, headers : {
      'accept': '*/*',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    getRepresentationProvider.setCategoryName(CategoryName);
    getRepresentationProvider.setCategoryId(CategoryId);
    getRepresentationProvider.setperticularCategoryDataAccordingDate(

        {
          "TotalInstallmentofplottypeCount":body["data"]["TotalInstallmentofplottypeCount"],
          "paidInstallmentofplottypeCount": body["data"]["paidInstallmentofplottypeCount"],
          "UnpaidInstallmentofplottypeCount":body["data"]["UnpaidInstallmentofplottypeCount"],
          "totalAmountofInstallment": body["data"]["totalAmountofInstallment"],
          "PaidtotalAmountofInstallment": body["data"]["PaidtotalAmountofInstallment"],
          "UnPaidtotalAmountofInstallment":body["data"]["UnPaidtotalAmountofInstallment"]

        }

    ).then((value) {
      print("Here is data Set ${body}");
    });

    return body;
  }
```

Provider code is below where perticularCategoryDataAccordingDate is set and reset:

```
   class RepresentationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  List perticularCategoryDataAccordingDate = [];


  Future setperticularCategoryDataAccordingDate(data) async {
    perticularCategoryDataAccordingDate.add(data);
    notifyListeners();
    print("object here $perticularCategoryDataAccordingDate");
  }




  Future resetPerticularCategoryDataAccordingDate() async {
    perticularCategoryDataAccordingDate = [];
    notifyListeners();
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => getPlotsGraphDataAccordingToCategoryAndDate(context,CategoryId,CategoryName,date);
  }
```

Comment: what if multiple function having reset providers in init?